# replacing stolen rear wheel. compatability question

Tags: road-bike, 7-speed

I recently had my rear wheel stolen, it was a 7 speed. In looking to replace it, most cassette/wheel combos I am finding are 8 speed. The shifters are old suicide shifters and the deralier is congruent with them, so I imagine as long as the cassette is the same gear or higher (7/8) Ill be ok.. True?

Comment: The hub size in the rear also matters.

Comment: I think an 8 speed would fit but you simply can't select either the top or bottom gear.  You can fit a 7 speed cassette on an 8 speed hub, with a spacer available from LBS.   Or look out for a bike coop in your area - 7 speed used wheels should be stocked, but you're unlikely to find them new.     Final option is to change the lot to 10 or 11 speed, but that has other problems like hub OLD width.  A friction stem shifter "should" work, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

The 7-speed cassette standard has been functionally discontinued for new wheels.  Most new wheels come in 8-10 or 8-11 speed compatibility.  Since the 7-speed cassette bodies were shorter, you can install a 7-speed cassette on a 8-speed body using a 4mm spacer behind the cassette.  Alternatively, as you said, you can use the 7 shifter on an 8 cassette, you'll just have to tune out one of the gears with the limiters and cable tension.

Comment: If they are friction shifters, you might be able to "reach" all 8 gears. You won't know until you try but I've had good luck in this regard.